# How to push changes to git hub?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

How to push changes to remote repository?

1. I had one local project then i push this project to remote repository.
2. Then I made some changes locally by creating a branch and merging it with master branch
3. Now i am not able to push these changes to remote repository I am getting an error "rejected fetch first".

Comment: Follow the instructions git is giving you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind+its+remote+counterpart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You face this when the local workspace is not compatible with the remote one. Maybe your remote repo contains work that local project doesn’t have. Do git pull before pushing.

Comment: thanks you so much Gow.